# Error: no suitable method found for showInputDialog en Java

Tags: java, javascript

Estoy intentado crear un programa que almacene matrículas y nombres para crear una base de datos, sin embargo, al momento de correrla me sale este error:

```
apturas.java:71: error: no suitable method found for showInputDialog(<null>,String,String,String,String)
         opcion_consultas=(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Consultas","1.Generales","2.Registro","3.Regresar"));
                                      ^
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Capturas.java:136: error: variable cancel is already defined in method main(String[])
         int cancel=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1. Fisica","2. Logica","3. Regresar");
             ^
Capturas.java:136: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
         int cancel=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1. Fisica","2. Logica","3. Regresar");
                                                                             ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
3 errors
```

que estoy haciendo mal en mi codigo?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Capturas{
   public static void main(String[]args){



      String[]nombre=new String[5];
      String auxnombre;
      int[]num=new int[5];         int opcion_consultas=0;
      int opcion_menu=0;           int encontrar=0;
      int capture1;                int cancel=0;
      int auxnum=0;                int back=0;
      int casillas=0;              int go=0;
      int x=0;                     int opcion_cambios=0;
      int y=0;
      int error;
      int otro=0;
      int yaesta=0;
      int renglon=0;
      int min;

      do
      {

         opcion_menu=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la opcion deseada: \n 1.Captura \n 2.Consulta \n 3.Cambios \n 4.Cancelaciones \n 5.Reinstalacion \n 6.Salida") );       
         if(opcion_menu==1)
         {
            if(casillas<4)
            {
               yaesta=0;
               auxnum=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingresa el numero contable"));

               for(x=1; x<=4; x++)
               {
                  if(auxnum==num[x])
                  {
                     yaesta=1;
                  }
               }
               if(yaesta==1)
               {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero ya esta registrado");
               }
               if(yaesta==0)

                  renglon=0;
               {


                  for(x=1; x<=4; x++)
                  {
                     if(nombre[x]!=null)
                     {
                        renglon=renglon+1;
                     }
                  }
                  renglon=renglon+1;
                  num[renglon]=auxnum;

                  nombre[renglon]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el Nombre");
                  casillas=casillas+1;
               }
            }
         }
         if(opcion_menu==2)
         {
         do{

         opcion_consultas=(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Consultas","1.Generales","2.Registro","3.Regresar"));
         if(opcion_consultas==2)
         {
         encontrar=0;
         auxnum=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\n Ingrese la matricula"));
         for(x=1; x<=5; x++)
         {
         if(auxnum==num[x])
         {
         encontrar=1;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro No." +x+"\n Nombre: " +nombre[x]+"Numero de matricula"+num[x]);
         }
         }

         if(encontrar==0)
         {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El numero de matricula no existe");
         }
         }
         if(opcion_consultas==1)
         {
         for(x=1; x<5; x++)
         {
         min=x;
         for(y=x+1; y<5; y++)
         {
         if(num[y]>=num[min])
         {
         min=y;
         }
         }
         if(x!=min)
         {
         auxnum=num[x];
         auxnombre=nombre[x];

         num[x]=num[min];
         nombre[x]=nombre[min];

         num[min]=auxnum;
         nombre[min]=auxnombre;
         }
         }
         for(x=5; x>=1; x--)
         {
         if(nombre[x]!=null)
           {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro"+x+"\n Nombre: "+nombre[x]+"Numero de matricula: "+num[x]);
          }
           }
         }

         if(opcion_consultas==3)
         {
         otro=1;
         }
         }while(otro!=1);
         }

         if(opcion_menu==3)
         {}
         if(opcion_menu==4)
         {
         do
         {
         int cancel=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1. Fisica","2. Logica","3. Regresar");
         if(cancel==1){}
         if(cancel==2){}
         if(cancel==3)
         {
         back=1;
         }
         }while(back!=1);
         }
         if(opcion_menu==5)
         {
         }
         if(opcion_menu==6)
         {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opcion de Salida");
         do{
         go=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Desea salir del programa? 1. Si 2. No"));
         if(go==0 || go>2)
         {
           JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ERROR");
         }
         } while(go==0 || go>2);
         if(go==1)
         {
           System.exit(0);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gracias por usar el programa");
         }
      }}while(opcion_menu!=6);

   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Stephanie. Cuando preguntes y pongas código, formatéalo como tal. Selecciona el código y dale click al símbolo de llaves (`{}`) que está en la parte superior del editor. Así será más fácil leerlo. Acabo de hacerlo por ti esta vez. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no hay ninguna firma del método `showInputDialog` que coincida con la que estas intentando usar. Revisa el mensaje de error que has puesto y utiliza una de ellas. En la documentación de Java te explica qué debes poner en cada argumento.